# Can I use MIUI's auto SMS + MMS backup + restore thing on another custom ICS rom?

Tags: sms, backup, mms, miui

MIUI's built in SMS + MMS backup works quite well. However, I want to try out new custom ROMs. Is it possible to add integration of that MIUI service onto another ICS rom?

Comment: No, that service is dependent on the MIUI framework. Maybe you can move the service to other ROMs but most likely it will never work. Unless the dev integrated some MIUI goodies :P

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** No you can't.

**Reason:** You can't install the MIUI Backup App on another rom, because it's a signed system APK.

**Solution:** Use a backup solution which is available for all roms. If you just want to backup and restore SMS, then use the free https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore

**Source:** I'm a MIUI Beta tester and former moderator on the original forum en.miui.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the MIUI specific functionality, but using Titanium backup you can backup your SMS and MMS:

- Open Titanium Backup
- Press the search icon at the top and then the filter icon which appears to the right of the search input box
- At the bottom of the 'Filters' Screen, press the "Create label" button
- Enter the label name - "SMS"
- Press the "Add/Remove elements _" button
- Find and check the "[SMS/MMS/APN] Dialer Storage 2.2" checkbox - It may be called 'Messages (SMS & MMS)' depending on what OS you're using.
- Press the "OK" button and then the "Save" button
- Press the back radio button
- Select the "Schedules" tab
- Press the "Add new schedule" button located at the bottom
- On the schedule that just appeared, titled 'Redo backups for newer app versions', press the "Edit" button
- On the top combo box select the arrow to pull down the menu.
- Select the "Backup all system data" option
- On the next combo box that says "No filtering", click the arrow to pull down a menu.
- You should see your label you created.
- Select your label.
- Select the time you want your backup to take place
- Select the days you want your backup to take place
- Press the "Save" button
- Check the "Enabled" check box to enable your schedule

Now Titanium Backup will automatically backup your messages at the specified time and day or days.

Note: You will need the Titanium backup pro key to access the batch operations.

You can also backup your call call history by adding '[CONTACTS/CALLS] Contacts Storage 2.2' or 'Call Log' to a label

Taken in part from [this guide on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1711066)

Comment: Backing up system(ie non-user) apps with Titanium Backup sometimes causes FC or crashes when restored to a different ROM (esp AOSP <-> OEM ROMs), I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can backup SMS, MMS and call logs to your GMail account with this [free app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=backup.email.inapp&hl=en). Being online, you wouldn't lose your backups even if wipe your sd card or lose your phone.

This is better than using Titanium Backup, as it can sometimes cause issues.